# Diagonalization of pauli matrices problems arise in magnetic field calculation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics

The Hamiltonian for an electron in a magnetic field $\vec{B}$ is $H=-\mu_B \vec{\sigma}\cdot \vec{B}$, where $\vec{\sigma}$ is the Pauli matrices

ie:
$\vec{\sigma_x}$=
$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$
$\vec{\sigma_y}$ =
$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i \\
i & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$
$\vec{\sigma_z}$=
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$
respectively.

In the calculation of quantum canonical ensemble, the evaluation of the density matrix along for the direction $\hat{n}$ is given by: $\frac{e^{-\beta H}}{tr{e^{-\beta H}}}$

It's clear that the trace of $\vec{\sigma_x}$ and $\vec{\sigma_y}$ vanish, thus diagonlization is required for calculation.

The diagonlization of hermitian matrices can be evaluated by:

1. Compute of eigenvalue of the matrix
2. Obtain the eigenvectors
3. Construct the unitary matrix from the eigenvectors
4. Apply unitary transformation $A'$=$UAU^{\dagger}$, however,

From my calculation, diagonlization of $\vec{\sigma_x}$ gives $\vec{\sigma_z}$, and diagonlization of $\vec{\sigma_y}$ gives $\vec{\sigma_x}$, however $\vec{\sigma_x}$ trace is zero, which makes the density matrix calculation not feasible.

Here are some question arise from this problems.

1. What is the significance of the diagonlization of Pauli matrices yield another Pauli matrices?
2. How to do a calculation if the magnetic field is pointing in y direction?
3. In this case, $\vec{\sigma_y}$ seems special as trace of $\vec{\sigma_z}$ and diagonlise $\vec{\sigma_x}$ is non-zero, how to account for that?

For the second question, I just realised I can diagonlise the matrix again, so in practical sense, the calculation is valid, that might have also solve the third question.

Answer (score 2):

What has to be diagonalized in this question is not the Pauli matrices, but the Hamiltonian:
$$
H=-\mu_B\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{B}=-\mu_B\left(\sigma_xB_x + \sigma_yB_y+\sigma_zB_z\right)
=-\mu_B
\begin{bmatrix}
B_z & B_x-iB_y\\
B_x+iB_y & -B_z
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The trace of all three Pauli matrices vanish. The process of *diagonalization* means that one produces a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal. All three matrices have two eigenvalues: $+1$ and $-1$. So, as a result their diagonal matrix all look like $\sigma_z$. The fact that $\sigma_z$ is already a diagonal matrix does not really make that much difference.

The trace of a matrix is also given by the sum of its eigenvalues. It gives you another way to check that all three Pauli matrices will have a trace of zero.

If the magnetic field points in the $y$-direction, then the appropriate Pauli matrix would be $\sigma_y$.

Answer (score 0):

The most general spinor (but not a mixed state) is:

$$ \psi = \left[ \begin{array}{c}\cos{\frac{\theta}2}e^{+i\phi/2} \\ \sin{\frac{\theta}2}e^{-i\phi/2}\end{array}\right]$$

which is a superposition of traditional spin up and down. (Note: all 2-state quantum systems have states described by this). What is unique to spin 1/2 is that $\psi$ is a pure spin up state along the axis defined by $\theta$ and $\phi$.

So, if I rotate my coordinate system to the new axis, it will be an eigenvector of $\sigma_z$ in those coordinates.

That means, if you take any (normalized) linear combination of the Pauli matrices: it will diagonalize to $\sigma_z$.